# Sending email only to active (unblocked) users of the site

Tags: 7, emails

How can I send email and notifications to the active (unlocked) users of the site? What modules do I need for that? Could you explain it clearly?

Already I'm using messaging, notifications and the [Mass contact](http://drupal.org/project/mass_contact) module. 
If I send mail through the Mass contact module, the blocked users also receive mails.

Answer (score 1):

Add a category in Mass Contact

http://localhost/sitename/admin/config/system/mass_contact/add

and "Roles to receive e-mail" , just check "authenticated user" and save configuration.

And "authenticated user" are active user not the blocked user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hook_mail_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_mail_alter/6) to check the emails before they go out and filter the users on your conditions before they actually send to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rules and VBO modules.